# Delete parts of an URL with REGEX

Tags: jquery, regex, wordpress, replace, url-rewriting

I am working with the wordpress search engine. I have 3 input fields for building a URL:

```
  <div id="cadenas"><div style="text-align:center">
    <form role="search" method="get" id="searchform" class="searchform" action="<?php echo esc_url( home_url( '/' ) ) ?>">
      <div>
        <input type="text" font color="#436b00" placeholder="Anchura" value="" name="s" id="anch">
        <input type="text" font color="#436b00" placeholder="Altura" value="" name="Y" id="altu">
        <input type="text" font color="#436b00" placeholder="Diametro" value="" name="R" id="dia">
        <input type="submit" id="searchsubmit2" value="Buscar">
      </div>
    </form>
  </div>
</div>
```

Assuming I put 10 in all the fields, it gives me a URL like this:

```
https:\\miurl.com\?s=10&Y=10&R=10
```

However I need my URL to be in this format:

```
https:\\miurl.com\?s=10Y10R10
```

I need to replace `&Y=` by only `Y` and `&R=` by only `R`. Or delete `&` and the second and third `=`. Both solutions are good. How can i do this? I think that the best way is using regex, but I don't know how.

Comment: In VSCode I would do a search and replace for example like: find: `&(.)=` replace: `$1`. Similar thing can be done with `sed` or other regex using programs.

Comment: Are you trying to re-route the URL on the server, or change it as you submit the form? The two approaches are massively different.

Comment: Hi, Rory. I need that it works with i submit the form

Comment: Hi, any idea? I'm still lost with this theme... :(